# CASE WHEN THEN min()

Tags: sql, sql-server, min, case-when

Assitance with the second WHEN of the CASE statement.
I need to code for the below scenario: in the event there are two records with PCC = NULL then choose the ProviderFinalTier with the lowest value. It's currently choosing the min providerfinaltier of the table.

[image]

```
<!-- language: lang-sql-->
UPDATE spc
SET ProviderTier = CASE WHEN (coalesce(spc.rulespecialtyid, spc.RenderingproviderspecialtyID)  = mft.SpecialtyID and coalesce(spc.RulePCC,spc.PCC) = mft.PCC ) THEN ProviderFinalTier
    WHEN  (coalesce(spc.rulespecialtyid, spc.RenderingproviderspecialtyID) = mft.SpecialtyID and mft.pcc is null) 
    THEN (Select min(ProviderFinalTier) from Common.medicarefinaltiers where coalesce(spc.rulespecialtyid, spc.RenderingproviderspecialtyID) = mft.SpecialtyID and mft.pcc is null)
    ELSE 2 END
from analysis.AnalysisMatchedClaims spc
left join Compass_REPORTING.dbo.Payer p on p.Payer_Key = spc.PayerKey
left join Common.medicarefinaltiers mft on /*mft.EmployerId = spc.EmployerId
                                  and */mft.ProviderID = spc.RenderingProviderId
                                  and mft.SpecialtyId = coalesce(spc.rulespecialtyid, spc.RenderingproviderspecialtyID)  
                                  and mft.PayerGroup = p.Payer_Group
WHERE spc.ProviderTier is null
  and (mft.pcc = coalesce(spc.RulePCC,spc.PCC) or mft.PCC is null)
  and spc.RuleClaimType = 'I'
```

Comment: Which DBMS? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ...

Comment: @ThorstenKettner SQL SERVER

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You want to choose the ProviderFinalTier with the lowest value, so you use `MIN(ProviderFinalTier)`. `MIN` gives you the lowest value, so what is the problem?

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] your question to contain the _shortest_ code you can come up with that reproduces the problem, along with some sample schema and input, and the desired and actual output. See [mcve] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for why this is important and some tips on how to do it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I tried that but got the following error: 'An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.'

Answer (score 1):

In this subquery:

```
Select min(ProviderFinalTier) 
from Common.medicarefinaltiers 
where coalesce(spc.rulespecialtyid, spc.RenderingproviderspecialtyID) = mft.SpecialtyID 
  and mft.pcc is null
```

you did not alias the table `Common.medicarefinaltiers` so any reference to `mft` is actually a reference to the outer joined table `Common.medicarefinaltiers`.

I think that you should provide an alias to the table and use that alias for the conditions:

```
Select min(m.ProviderFinalTier) 
from Common.medicarefinaltiers m 
where coalesce(spc.rulespecialtyid, spc.RenderingproviderspecialtyID) = m.SpecialtyID 
  and m.pcc is null
```